# Why my answer is not correct about select_from_nobel_tutorial #14

Tags: mysql, sql

**[UPDATE]** Finally figure out, I forget to put subject as ORDER BY Column

---

All:

I am pretty new to SQL, I wonder how to solve the last question in SQLZOO select from nobel tutorial last question:

http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial

```
14.
The expression subject IN ('Chemistry','Physics') can be used as a value - it will be 0 or 1.
Show the 1984 winners and subject ordered by subject and winner name; but list Chemistry and Physics last.
```

I thought is should be(in **MYSQL** version):

```
SELECT winner, subject
  FROM nobel
 WHERE yr=1984
 ORDER BY subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry'),winner
```

But it gives me Error: `"Wrong answer. Some of the data is incorrect."`

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks, could you help with another( the #8 ): http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQLZOO:SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial   I thought it should be:  select name, population, area from world where not ( (area>3000000 and population>250000000) and (area<=3000000 and population<=250000000) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the question linked is below:-

```
SELECT  winner, subject
  FROM nobel
 WHERE yr=1984
 ORDER BY subject IN ('Physics','Chemistry'), subject, winner
```

Using the case statement will get you what you want in terms of Physics and Chemistry appearing at the end.